# Angular's ControlValueAccessor has a `null` initial value?

Tags: javascript, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm using Nativescript  + Angular

```
| nativescript     │ 3.4.3           │ 3.4.3          │ Up to date  │
│ tns-core-modules │ 3.4.1           │ 3.4.1          │ Up to date  │
│ tns-android      │ 3.4.2           │ 3.4.2          │ Up to date  │
```

I'm using a code which creates a custom `ngModel` value  using the `ControlValueAccessor` interface .
As you can see I have 2 TextFields  and a json showing the model value.

[image]

This is how I activate the component with value :

**home.component.ts**

```
export class HomeComponent  {

 dataModel = {
    a:1,b:2
};

...
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<StackLayout >
    <app-flag  [(ngModel)]="dataModel"></app-flag>
</StackLayout>
```

— This is the actual component markup code :

**flag.component.html**

```
<GridLayout rows="auto,auto,auto"   columns="*" >
        <TextField [(ngModel)]="innerValue.a" row="0" ></TextField>
        <TextField [(ngModel)]="innerValue.b" row="1"></TextField>
        <Label textWrap="true" text="{{innerValue | json}}" row=3></Label>
</GridLayout>
```

**flag.component.ts**

```
export class FlagComponent implements  ControlValueAccessor {

    innerValue= { a: 1, b: 2 }

    writeValue(value: any) {
        this.innerValue = value;
    }
...}
```

This code works fine , and does show the values in json. But the problem is that at t=0 , there is an error :

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of null

After  testings  - it seems that at first -  the value in `writeValue` is  null.

**Question**

Something is not right here. Even if there's a delay in `writeValue` values - it still has a public property with initial values :

[image]

So how come it's `null` ?

[**Playground**](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=sw5KMY&v=2)

BTW - in native angular it doesn't happen - same code :

[**https://plnkr.co/edit/TyoCgvb8i8zSryxC9NXb?p=preview**](https://plnkr.co/edit/TyoCgvb8i8zSryxC9NXb?p=preview)

Comment: Is it correct `innerValue: { a: 1, b: 2 }`? You simply define type not value

Comment: @yurzui Hi. fixed but still - https://i.imgur.com/H6PmZMl.jpg . I can solve it by wrapping `<ng-container *ngIf="innerValue"` - but it's a hacky solution which I prefer to avoid

Comment: @yurzui Update : it is becuase of the `form` tag (which I don't have in Nativescript). If I remove the form tag - [i Also see the error here in Angular web](https://plnkr.co/edit/2MaEsD7Ru5aGu6VH6Z5U?p=preview) As you can see here : https://i.imgur.com/hcOmYzj.jpg . Question is now how to deal with it......:(

Comment: update #2 - [this is my current solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/cbOUCX7UEKBgq16xWF4c?p=preview) ( using ngcontainer) . Will be glad to know if any other path of solution ?

Comment: First of all https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14988

Comment: Next, If you have standalone control then it will be initialized immediately without any delay https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/fab6b39c3de23ae8690ae2a64860933b89cc4691/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L209-L225

Comment: @yurzui I can't help it. You always make me look stupid  ..... I;'ve been working on this for the last 2 days and didnt get to this github issue -becausee I was sure it is a problem with my side. Thanks !!! - like always 

Comment: If you wrap control in form then initialization will be scheduled https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/fab6b39c3de23ae8690ae2a64860933b89cc4691/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_form.ts#L117

Comment: Yeah but there's no Form in nativescript unfortunately .... :-(

Comment: Try using `ngForm` attribute instead of `form` element https://plnkr.co/edit/SSgX4uEszzz4Rj25YaWz?p=preview See also available selectors for NgForm directive https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/fab6b39c3de23ae8690ae2a64860933b89cc4691/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_form.ts#L67

Comment: @yurzui update : Your solution worked . The error was replaced by requirement to add a `name`. https://i.imgur.com/wrhdIVN.jpg
Please ( if you want - post it as answer so I can select it).Thank you _very_ much.